# How do i reverse a Phaser tween?

Tags: typescript, phaser-framework

In Phaser, I use a tween to move a sprite on button click ie.

```
var tween = this.game.add.tween(sprite)
    .to({ y: destinationY) }, 400, Phaser.Easing.Bounce.InOut));
tween.start();
```

How do I revert the tween so that when I click on another button the sprite goes back to its original position?

Comment: Why did the question get voted down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reverse the tween when a button is clicked just have your button run a tween that does so. :)

In your particular case, that would probably involve saving the `originalY` in addition to the `destinationY` that you're saving now.

Then run your new tween with that value.

Something like this for your existing button:

```
// Save the sprites current position first to originalY.
var tween = this.game.add.tween(sprite)
    .to({ y: destinationY) }, 400, Phaser.Easing.Bounce.InOut));
tween.start();
```

Then use it in your new button.

```
var tween = this.game.add.tween(sprite)
    .to({ y: originalY) }, 400, Phaser.Easing.Bounce.InOut));
tween.start();
```

Comment: I thought to do this and it is very easy to achieve indeed... I was hoping there was a way to reverse without adding another tween and essentially rewriting the code. It would be useful to do this when tweens are more complex. Also, I have a large number of tweens that I need to reverse...

Comment: There is a `[reverse](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.6/Phaser.Tween.html#reverse)` property on `Phaser.Tween`, but per the official *A Guide to the Tween Manager* only seems to work if the tween is currently running. The example has the tween running in a loop along a set, closed, path.